# Angular HTTP Service returns results buried in an object, how to add the type?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an Angular service called FilmService, that uses the HttpClient module to fetch data from an API. When a component uses this service, it gets an array of films of type `Film`. However, the API buries these film objects in a `results` object (e.g. `{results: []}`). I've used the `map` operator to process the Observable and return the `results` object. However my IDE is complaining about the type of `results` in my `map` function:

> Property 'results' does not exist on type 'Object'.

How do I correctly type the service method?

Please see my code below.

**Interface: Film.ts:**

```
export interface Film {
  id: number;
  title: string;
}
```

**FilmService method:**

```
getMostPopular(): Observable<Film[]> {
  return this.http.get(this.apiUrl, {
    params: {
      api_key: this.apiKey,
      sort_by: 'popularity.desc'
    }
  }).pipe(
    map((films) => films.results) // Property 'results' does not exist on type 'Object'.
  );
}
```

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/http#type-checking-the-response

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your api buries all responses in the same kind of wrapper object, you can define a generic response type. The `HttpClient` has a generic type parameter (for most operations), that represents the return type.

Something like this:

```
export interface ApiResponse<T> {
    results: T;
    errors: string[];
}
```

then use it in the following manner:

```
return this.http.get<ApiResponse<Film[]>>(...).pipe(map(response => response.results));
```